# Matrix to Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have a text file that has the following input and i'm asked to draw graphs from the input but i'm not quite sure how each input turned into the given graphs. I know the first line means number of vertices but next lines don't look like a symmetrical matrix to me!! I understand the first two graphs but after that not sure! I know it's trivial but Please help.

```
1

2 
1

4
101
 10
  1
5
0011
 011
  11
   0

5
1000
 101
  10
   1 

6
11110
 1011
  101
   11
    1

6
11100
 1010
  001
   00
    0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your thrid example in the picture, a typical matrix encoding would be:

```
  0123
0 0101
1 1010
2 0101
3 1010
```

meaning that node 0 is not adjacent to itself (node 0), adjacent to 1, not adjacent to 2 and adjacent to 3, etc. This is a [Adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

It seems that you are dealing with undirected graphs, so the adjacency matrix would contain redundant information, when you know that 0 is adjacent to 1, you know that 1 is adjacent to 0, no need to write that information a second time. Therefore it makes sense to have a slightly different encoding, eliminating all redundance. Under the assumption that a node cannot be adjacent to itself and that your fourth example, in the picture, is supposed to represent the fourth encoding:

```
  1234
0 0011
1  011
2   11
3    0
```

I would interpret as follows, that node 0 is not adjacent to 1, not adjacent to 2, but adjacent to 3 and 4. Node 1 is not adjacent to 2, but adjacent to 3 and 4, etc. As you can see, you have described the relation of node 0 to node 1 in the first row, so you don't need to describe that in the second row again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the upper triangle of an adjacency matrix. Add a zero to each row for the diagonal and then invert the triangle to make square

6
**1 1 1 0 0** *0*
**1 0 1 0** *0* 0
**0 0 1** *0* 0 0
**0 0** *0* 0 0 0
**0** *0* 0 1 0 1
*0* 0 0 1 1 1